# Using Nokogiri to scrape data: "undefined method `text'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri in my Rails application to scrape information from a website but am getting:

```
NoMethodError: "undefined method `text' for nil:NilClass".
```

This is sample code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'  

url = "https://btc-e.com/exchange/btc_usd/"
doclink = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doclink.at_css(".orderStats:nth-child(1) strong").text
```

I am trying to pull in the "Last Price" listed in the URL. I used the "SelectorGadget" Chrome Add-in to find the CSS description. I also tried using `.orderStats strong` but got the same no method error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are referring to uses JavaScript to populate itself. Since Nokigiri doesn't execute JS, the page Nokigiri fetches is pretty useless:

```
<html>
<head><title>loading</title></head>
<body>
<p>Please wait...</p>
<script>/* POPULATES THE PAGE */</script>
</body>
</html>
```

One solution would be to use a scraper that executes JS, e.g. Capybara+PhantomJS. Here's an article that describes how: http://www.chrisle.me/2012/12/scraping-html5-sites-using-capybara-phantomjs/. Google for more info.